# Ember session initializer causing page reload for every route

Tags: session, ember.js, ember-cli

I'm building a Twitter based app in Ember-CLI and have a session initializer to ensure users are authenticated on each route. Users login via Twitter using the passport-twitter module for Express.js. I've done this before in a previous app and it's fine, but in this app I've noticed that every route reloads the page.

I've stripped everything out to just an h1 tag per route and it still reloads the page. As soon as I remove the initializer and beforeModel hook below however, everything works as expected with no page reload.

initializers/session.js :

```
name: 'session',
initialize: function(container, app) {
  var Session = Ember.Object.extend({
    user: null,
      isAuthenticated: function() {
      return this.get('user') !=null;
    }.property('user')
  });
  app.register('session:main', Session);
  app.inject('route', 'session', 'session:main');
  app.inject('controller', 'session', 'session:main');
}
```

routes/application.js

```
beforeModel: function() {
  var route = this;
  var promise = this.store.find('user', {operation: 'authenticated'});
  return promise.then(function(users) {
    if (users && users.get('length') > 0) {
      var user = users.get('firstObject');
      route.set('session.user', user);
    }
    return users;
  });
},
```

I've tried setting {singleton: true} in app.register just in case, but that doesn't work either.

I'm using a more recent version of Ember 1.11.1 and Ember-CLI 0.2.3 and I'm not sure how to even debug this. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Any console errors, warnings before redirects? Maybe try using JavaScript debugger for example in Chrome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit of a guess, since I cannot see what exactly do you mean by "reloading the page". I'm going to assume it's "nothing rendered/blank page" phase.

From [Ember's beforeModel documentation](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_beforeModel):

> if the value returned from this hook is a promise, the transition will pause until the transition resolves. Otherwise, non-promise return values are not utilized in any way.

`beforeModel` is **first** hook on entry, a place, where one can decide about driving user off the route, so nothing will render until given promise/transition is resolved. If your application is setup in a way hook is run repeatedly it might result in "refreshing-like" experience.

You could either wait for transition to finish `transition.then(..your setup...)`, not return a promise, or set `session.user` value to a promise.

Comment: It won't get called on every transition, it will get called on the first load of the application.

Comment: It's true, a bit odd and counter intuitive for me. Do you have per chance any notion in documentation supporting why this is happening?

Comment: I've edited information about hook being run repeatedly but left the rest, since based on provided code I believe the problem might be caused by re-running the hook for some reason.

Comment: When you go to a URL, Ember will activate all of the route segments. Since application is the implicit root segment, it gets activated the first time you enter any of the routes in your application. I think the API docs might mention this.

Comment: Since this is offtopic I defined this matter as [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32331491/why-applicationroute-doesnt-react-to-transitions)

Answer (score 0):

I think you were on the right trail with `{ singleton: false }`, but I believe that has changed in the last few versions of Ember. According to [the guide](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/understanding-ember/dependency-injection-and-service-lookup/#toc_dependency-injection-with-code-register-inject-code), you need to use `{ instantiate: false }` to tell the Ember container that you're giving it an already instantiated object. Also, be sure to use `Ember.Object.create()` instead of `Ember.Object.extend()`. That will ensure that you get the same session instance every time.

(This actually assumes that you have code somewhere that redirects/refreshes if the session isn't active, but I'm assuming that is the case because if not, why would you even have the session?)